# Is it possible to use a Kleene Operator for Flex Formatters?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

is it possible to use a Kleene Operator (Kleene Star) for the Formatters?
I want to use a phoneFormatter, which puts a minus after the 5th number and afterwards it should be possible to have a variable number of numbers. 
E.g.: 0172-555666999, 0160-44552 etc.

That is how I started, but I don't know which character belongs after the last hash (it is not a star, I already tried it ;-) ):

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <mx:PhoneFormatter id="mPhoneFormat"
                           formatString="####-#"/>

    </fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `PhoneFormatter` expects the input string to have the same number of characters as the format string. They don't support regular expression patterns (like * to match the element zero or more times).

However, it's pretty easy to make your own formatter. To do this, I extended the `PhoneFormatter` class and overrode its `format()` method. I copied and pasted the original `format()` method and made the following modifications:

- comment out the code that compared the length of the source string with the length of the format string
- compare the length of the formatted string. If the original string is longer, append the remaining chars from the original string to the formatted string.

This probably won't handle all of your use cases, but it should be pretty straightforward to modify this to your needs.

```
package
{
    import mx.formatters.PhoneFormatter;
    import mx.formatters.SwitchSymbolFormatter;

    public class CustomPhoneNumberFormatter extends PhoneFormatter
    {
        public function CustomPhoneNumberFormatter()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function format(value:Object):String
        {
            // Reset any previous errors.
            if (error)
                error = null;

            // --value--

            if (!value || String(value).length == 0 || isNaN(Number(value)))
            {
                error = defaultInvalidValueError;
                return "";
            }

            // --length--

            var fStrLen:int = 0;
            var letter:String;
            var n:int;
            var i:int;

            n = formatString.length;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                letter = formatString.charAt(i);
                if (letter == "#")
                {
                    fStrLen++;
                }
                else if (validPatternChars.indexOf(letter) == -1)
                {
                    error = defaultInvalidFormatError;
                    return "";
                }
            }

//          if (String(value).length != fStrLen)
//          {
//              error = defaultInvalidValueError;
//              return "";
//          }

            // --format--

            var fStr:String = formatString;

            if (fStrLen == 7 && areaCode != -1)
            {
                var aCodeLen:int = 0;
                n = areaCodeFormat.length;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (areaCodeFormat.charAt(i) == "#")
                        aCodeLen++;
                }
                if (aCodeLen == 3 && String(areaCode).length == 3)
                {
                    fStr = String(areaCodeFormat).concat(fStr);
                    value = String(areaCode).concat(value);
                }
            }

            var dataFormatter:SwitchSymbolFormatter = new SwitchSymbolFormatter();
            var source:String = String(value);
            var returnValue:String = dataFormatter.formatValue(fStr, value);
            if (source.length > returnValue.length)
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + source.substr(returnValue.length-1);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does not solve the problem in all cases but that's what I wanted to know ;-). I don't know why, but there's a little bug in your solution, if I enter exactly 6 numeric characters, I lose for any reason the last numeric character... ("0123456" -> "01234-5")

Comment: Yeah, I think I hurried through that. The comparison I make at the end (`if source.length > returnValue.length`) is not appending the 6th character b/c the formatted string (returnValue) is the same length as the source string... the formatted string has a dash in it. One quick and dirty solution is: `if source.length > returnValue.length -1`. But that only works when the format string has 1 dash. A more proper solution would be to subtract out all the dashes from the formatted string, and then compare the lengths...